# IntelliJ Java 17 not running Snowpark Java

Tags: intellij-idea, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, java-17

I running this examples https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/java/example and not working. It's weird because works one time and then don't working anymore.

Follow the full error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDFClassPath$ (in unnamed module @0x4218d6a3) cannot access class sun.net.www.ParseUtil (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.net.www to unnamed module @0x4218d6a3
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDFClassPath$.$anonfun$getPathUsingClassLoader$1(UDFClassPath.scala:101)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDFClassPath$.getPathUsingClassLoader(UDFClassPath.scala:89)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDFClassPath$.getPathForClass(UDFClassPath.scala:72)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDFClassPath$.<init>(UDFClassPath.scala:23)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.UDFClassPath$.<clinit>(UDFClassPath.scala)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.Session.sessionInfo$lzycompute(Session.scala:86)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.Session.sessionInfo(Session.scala:76)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.Session$.com$snowflake$snowpark$Session$$setActiveSession(Session.scala:1195)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.Session$SessionBuilder.createInternal(Session.scala:1327)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.Session$SessionBuilder.create(Session.scala:1320)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark_java.SessionBuilder.create(SessionBuilder.java:71)
    at com.carnegielearning.snowpark.SnowparkTemplate.main(SnowparkTemplate.java:22)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried reinstall Intellij IDEA with different version (2019, 2020, 2021 and 2022) but nothing work. I tried too to run in Eclipse too but the error is the same. And tried using different version of java like 11, 15, 16, 17 and 19. Nothing works!

Comment: The root cause is `cannot access class sun.net.www.ParseUtil (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.net.www to unnamed module @0x4218d6a3`. You need to use something like `--add-exports java.base/sun.net.www=xxx` to expose that module or the snowflake library should fix that code.

Answer (score 1):

The Snowpark supports Java 11.x.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/java/prerequisites

So, for now, you can't use Java 17.

Answer (score 1):

I use snowpark with Temurin 17 (eclipse JDK) and Snowpark 1.8.0.

I get the same error that you get:
`cannot access class sun.net.www.ParseUtil (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.net.www to unnamed module @0x4218d6a3`

I added the following JVM args to my run configuration and it works just fine:

```
--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
```